# Mesos-master is exiting quietly (possibly because of segmentation fault) on Fedora 25 when being accessed on port 5050

Tags: fedora, mesos, fedora-25

I installed Mesos on Fedora 25 using `sudo yum install mesos` and it worked fine.

Starting Mesos master also worked fine, as per instructions here: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/ApacheMesos

I am able to see the `mesos-master` process running, with `ps -e | grep mesos` yields nothing.

However, if I try to access `localhost:5050` then **mesos-master** dies silently and further `ps -e | grep mesos`.

Even if I start a local Zookeeper instance and then use the `--zk` parameter with `sudo -u mesos /usr/sbin/mesos-master ...`, I get proper registration of the master into Zookeeper, but accessing the master via port 5050 still makes it die.

A run with INFO-level logging shows that `mesos-master` is dying with 'Segmentation fault'.

```
I1222 09:10:01.897171  3537 replica.cpp:658] Replica received learned notice for position 32
I1222 09:10:01.897917  3537 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (18 bytes) to leveldb took 691597ns
I1222 09:10:01.898047  3537 leveldb.cpp:401] Deleting ~2 keys from leveldb took 24314ns
I1222 09:10:01.898114  3537 replica.cpp:679] Persisted action at 32
I1222 09:10:01.898135  3537 replica.cpp:664] Replica learned TRUNCATE action at position 32
*** Aborted at 1482397807 (unix time) try "date -d @1482397807" if you are using GNU date ***
PC: @                0x1 (unknown)
Segmentation fault
```

The crash takes place even if I try to connect a `mesos-slave` to the master via zookeeper - which tells that the problem is not with the zk/master/slave setup but with the fact that the master responding to port 5050 makes it crash.

**fedoraproject.org** states that the Mesos RPM was created for `Fedora 21` and I am running on Fedora **25**.

Wasn't the RPM supposed to be backward compatible, considering that it is present in `Fedora 25` repositories?

Comment: Are you running `mesos-master` in standalone mode (non-HA) - just single instance?

Comment: Tried both, if exists silently pretty much the same way.